# Bed, bath and bejesus

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

In an interview with Craig Ferguson (CF) at The (now late) Late Late Show, Billy Connolly (BC) says https://youtu.be/wkqkpvA7Oq0?t=8m24s

> BC: So now they're all gathering on Princess Street in Edinburgh, outside.
>   ...
>   BC: Freezing a bejesus off you.
>   CF: You can't say that...
>   ...
>   BC: I said "Bejesus!"
>   ...
>   BC: It's like "Bed, bath and bejesus"

As I understand "bejesus" is usually used make an emphasis, so that *Freezing a bejesus off you* would mean something like "It's damm cold."
But I can't understand the meaning of the last *It's like "Bed, bath and bejesus."*

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a play on words. There is a store called "bed bath and beyond". He substitutes "beyond" for another word that starts with "b". This is not a very common expression; I have never heard it before.

Comment: The remark is funny in part because it's **not** a common expression.

Comment: Reminds me of the Simpsons episode set in the 19th century: Pone Pelts and Beyond.  https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Pone,_Pelts_and_Beyond

Comment: More than "not a common expression", I think it was something he made up in the moment. Just a one-off joke.